# Pictures do not open in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I received a google sheet file that has both text, links and pictures. However pictures are uploading randomly and there are always a lot of them that won't upload.

Google rep said this :

here is failsafe way to use images in google sheets

put images in a shared folder on google drive
right click images - & get sharable link
paste that link into cell - in example below column F5:F8
formula to put image in cell can be a single cell - or array formula in B5

for single image
=If(F5="",,Image("http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&mid(F5,34,33),2))

an arrayformula for a column of images
=Arrayformula(If(F5:F8="",,Image("http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&mid(F5:F8,34,33),2)))

But we did it this way so it isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`IMAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333) with pictures hosted on Drive, you have to keep in mind that «*You can only use URLs that aren't hosted at drive.google.com. SVG file format isn't supported*». Therefore, you can't use the hosted Drive pics into the formula. I was able to run your formula by using an image hosted outside of Drive:

```
=IF(F5="",,IMAGE("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Variegated_grasshopper_%28Zonocerus_variegatus%29.jpg/1024px-Variegated_grasshopper_%28Zonocerus_variegatus%29.jpg",2))
```